# Sorting a date attached to a note

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort a list with a note to it.

For instance:

```
list = ['2015-12-01: remember groceries' , '2017-12-21 : buy presents'] etc.
```

My problem is that I need to sort the list by the dates and still have the notes attached to that date. Any ideas how to do this? Dictionary? Lists within lists?

I know how to sort just the dates, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort it with the notes attached to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: Doesn't `sort(list)` do exactly what you are asking?

Comment: (Don't call your variable `list`, though.)

Comment: You could use numpy argsort to retrieve the indices, then apply those indices to several arrays containing your different data types.

Comment: Dates given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format can be sorted chronologically as strings using `sorted()`. It is when you have `DD-MM-YYYY` or other formats that the problems start.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data all look like this:

- Every entry in the array is a string
- Every entry begins with the date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Then you could do simply do

```
list.sort();
```

This would sort the strings in your array lexicographically, and for dates in the above format this is equivalent to sorting them in the normal time line. This would not work if your dates also have other formats like 'YYYY-M-DD'.

Answer (score 1):

Your date presentation is sortable as is. just

```
res = sorted(list)
```

Comment: Well this is embarrasing...hmm maybe there was something wrong with my original list or something. Thanks !!

Comment: If something is wrong, show the result to undestand the problem

Answer (score 0):

just go for a list of tuples. this is always sorted by the first element and you can get your date value and your note separately

```
list = [('2015-12-01', 'remember groceries') , ('2017-12-21', 'buy presents'), ('2015-12-21', 'xxx')]
print(sorted(list))
print(list[0][1], list[1][1])
```